# How to stretch any div height up to the end of the browser window from the middle

Tags: css, html, height

I need to stretch `div.leftContent3` and `div.bodyContent3` till the end of the browser window without having a scrollbar using CSS alone (no jQuery or JavaScript), and do so in a way that also supports IE7. how to do that?

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="leftPanel">
        <div class="leftContent1">
            Left Content1
        </div>
        <div class="leftContent2">
            Left Content2
        </div>
        <div class="leftContent3">
            Left Content3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodyContent">
        <div class="bodyContent1">
            Body Content1
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent2">
            Body Content2
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent3">
            Body Content3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .parent {
    height: 100%;
}
.parent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
.leftPanel {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
.bodyContent {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
}
.leftContent1, .leftContent2, .leftContent3,
.bodyContent1, .bodyContent2, .bodyContent3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}
.leftContent1 {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 125px;
}
.leftContent2 {
    background-color: #999999;
    height: 150px;
}
.leftContent3 {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: inherit;
}
.bodyContent1 {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    height: 120px;
}
.bodyContent2 {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 80px;
}
.bodyContent3 {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: instead of  height:inherit; if I use 100%, then also it gives the same result.

Comment: I highly doubt it is feasible. In my expereince mixing absolute dimensions and relative ones (so px and %) is a very bad practice. You should use only relative dimensions or if you cannot, you should use javascript

Comment: Thank u for your comment Andre. But I did not use the Position: relative or absolute property in the CSS, neither I can use JavaScript to achieve this. Please provide any CSS solution for that , if u have. Is it really unachievable without JavaScript.

Comment: I was not talking about `position: relative/absolute`. I was talking about fixed dimensions given in pixel. I think you should give relative percentage to every div. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/7QcZb/1/). I gave the third div a `72%` instead of the "correct" `73%` so that the `border` property would not oversize the total dimension (if you give `73%` the page will be like `101%` instead of `100%`)

Comment: Hi Andre.. The height of the Left Content and Body Content are not same and not fixed too. So I cannot fix the height. Please let me know how to solve this in a dynamic situation.

Comment: I think you must stop for a while and think deeper to what you want to achieve. The example you gave doesn't seem very explainatory to me as it has fixed dimensions, but now you say divs cannot have fixed dimensions. Clarify your head and then make an appropriate example.

Answer (score 1):

if I did understand your question, you can achieve your goal by applying some `position:relative;`, `position:absolute;` with `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`:

See the working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7QcZb/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="leftPanel">
        <div class="leftContent1">Left Content1</div>
        <div class="leftContent2">Left Content2</div>
        <div class="leftContent3">
          Left Content3 This Section needs to beexpand till the end of
          the browser window Without having browser scroll
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bodyContent">
        <div class="bodyContent1">Body Content1</div>
        <div class="bodyContent2">Body Content2</div>
        <div class="bodyContent3">
          Body Content3 This Section needs to beexpand till the end of
          the browser window Without having browser scroll
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body, .parent { height:100%; }

.parent { margin:auto; width:1000px; }

.leftPanel { float:left; width:200px; height:100%; position:relative; }
.bodyContent { float:left; width:800px; height:100%; position:relative; }

.leftContent1, .leftContent2, .leftContent3, .bodyContent1,
.bodyContent2, .bodyContent3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.leftContent1 { background-color:#cccccc; height: 125px; }
.leftContent2 { background-color:#999999; height: 150px; top:125px; }
.leftContent3 { background-color:#ff0000; top:275px; bottom:0; }

.bodyContent1 { background-color:#fcfcfc; height:120px; }
.bodyContent2 { background-color:orange; height:80px; top:120px; }
.bodyContent3 { background-color:#00ff00; top:200px; bottom: 0; }
```

#### Note

You can drag the split bar of the Fiddle to see the two divs growing and shrinking.

To read about this:

[CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [CSS position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Thanks Zuul for your reply. But I cannot fix the top position for any div, since the contents are dynamic. Can you please share something without fixing the top position